# Mac book pro charger came with twisted connector tip

Tags: macbook-pro, charger

I just got my new macbook pro out of the box, and for my surprise i also noticed the sharp bent on the tip of the charger. Can i 'undo' this bent?

[image]

I already
had an 'incident' where my charger was 'decapitated' due to stress on this region. I mean...why they fold it like this? it's just too stupid.

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to do anything. The cable is made of a couple layers of isolation warped around copper. Each material has its own elasticity and there is friction where the materials meet. The metal inside the cable is not irreversibly bent. It's the friction that's keeping it this way. Everything will move back in place.